# Racket Code: Higher-Order Functions

Tags: dictionary, lambda, racket, higher-order-functions

I'm trying to implement higher level functions in my Racket code, specifically with regards to this function:

```
(define (indivisible e L)
  (map (remove 0 ((map ((lambda (x y) (modulo x y))) L e)))))
```

Essentially, I'm trying to remove all the elements that are divisible by e from the list. However, it keeps giving me an error that says that "the expected number of arguments did not match the given number (0 vs 2)". Why is this so?

Answer (score 1):

Several places you have two sets of parentheses. Unless the parentheses are a part of a special form or macro, eg. `let`, it represent an application. Ie.

```
((lambda (x y) (modulo x y)))
```

Here the form `(lambda ...)` is evaluated and become a function. The second set of parentheses calls this function **with no arguments**. Since you have two arguments, `x` and `y` and not supplying any in your application it signals an error.

Another place where you do the same is around `(map ....)`. Since I know `map` always evaluates to a list or null it looks kind of strange that you call it as a function `((map ...))`.

If you are more familiar with [algol languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generational_list_of_programming_languages#ALGOL_based) like python, what you are doing is like `someFunc(arg1 args2)()` where you clearly see `someFunc` needs to return a function wince it's immediately called afterwards. The same in Scheme looks like `((some-func arg1 arg2))`.

`remove` removes the first argument from the second argument list. It does not return a function so the outer `map` won't work.

To solve this I think you are looking for [`filter`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=remove#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._filter%29%29). You only need to make a predicate that is `#f` for the elements you don't want and you're done.